# Can someone verify why the following alternate derivation regarding a non-central chi distribution giving different answer?

Tags: probability-distributions, definite-integrals, solution-verification, chi-squared

I am having trouble to understand why an alternate derivation of mine related to the Eq.(10) of this [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=8768042) is not matching with the result in the paper. First, let me describe the problem.

The paper considers the random vectors $\mathbf{X},\mathbf{Y}\in \mathbb{R}^n$, such that $\mathbf{X}\sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{I}_n),\ \mathbf{Y}\vert \mathbf{X}=\mathbf{x}\sim\mathbf{N}(\mathbf{x},\sigma^2\mathbf{I}_n)$. Then they evaluate $f_{\mathbf{Y},\|\mathbf{X}\|}(\mathbf{y},t)$ as below: 
\begin{align}
f_{\mathbf{Y},\|\mathbf{X}\|}(\mathbf{y},t) & = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f_{\mathbf{Y}\vert \mathbf{X}}(\mathbf{y}\vert \mathbf{x})f_{\|\mathbf{X}\|\vert \mathbf{X}}(t\vert \mathbf{x})f_{\mathbf{X}}(\mathbf{x})d\mathbf{x}\\
\ & = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{e^{-\|\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}\|^2/2\sigma^2}}{(2\pi\sigma^2)^{n/2}}\delta(\|\mathbf{x}\|-t)\frac{e^{-\|\mathbf{x}\|^2/2}}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}d\mathbf{x}.\tag{1}
\end{align} 
In the above $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the $l_2$ norm. Beyond the above step they utilize a spherical coordinate transformation, utilize the fact that $\|\mathbf{x}\|=t$, and utilize the rotational invariance of the Normal distribution to conclude that \begin{align}
f_{\mathbf{Y},\|\mathbf{X}\|}(\mathbf{y},t) & = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}e^{-t^2/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma^2}}f_{\mathrm{Chi}}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{\sigma^2}};n,\frac{\|\mathbf{y}\|}{\sqrt{\sigma^2}}\right)\tag{2},
\end{align}
where $f_{\mathrm{Chi}}(x;n,\lambda)$ is the density of the [non-central Chi distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi_distribution) with parameters $n,\lambda$. Please see the paper mentioned above to find details about the derivation.

Now I have tried to express Eq.(1) in an alternate way as below: 
\begin{align}
f_{\mathbf{Y},\|\mathbf{X}\|}(\mathbf{y},t) & = \frac{e^{-\|\mathbf{y}\|^2/2(\sigma^2+1)}}{(2\pi(\sigma^2+1))^{n/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{e^{-\|\mathbf{x}-\frac{\mathbf{y}}{\sigma^2+1}\|^2/\left(\frac{2\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+1}\right)}}{(2\pi\frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+1})^{n/2}}\delta(\|\mathbf{x}\|-t)d\mathbf{x}\tag{3},
\end{align}
where I have used $$\frac{\|\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}\|^2}{2\sigma^2}+\frac{\|\mathbf{x}\|^2}{2}=\frac{\sigma^2+1}{2\sigma^2}\left\|\mathbf{x}-\frac{\mathbf{y}}{\sigma^2+1}\right\|^2+\frac{\|\mathbf{y}\|^2}{2(\sigma^2+1)}.$$ I think the integral in Eq.(3) is nothing but the density of the random variable $\|\mathbf{Z}\|$ where $\mathbf{Z}\sim \mathcal{N}(\frac{\mathbf{y}}{\sigma^2+1},\frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+1}\mathbf{I}_n)$. However, in that case,  the right hand side (RHS) of Eq.(3) seems to me to be proportional to $$\frac{e^{-\|\mathbf{y}\|^2/2(\sigma^2+1)}}{(2\pi(\sigma^2+1))^{n/2}}f_{\mathrm{Chi}}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{\sigma^2/(\sigma^2+1)}};n,\frac{\|\mathbf{y}\|}{\sqrt{\sigma^2(\sigma^2+1)}}\right).$$ This is different than the RHS of Eq.(2) in that the first argument inside the Chi density are not quite the same, and more importantly, there is a term containing $\|\mathbf{y}\|$, and not $t$ in the exponential outside the density.

This disparity is troubling me a lot, but I don't see why this has happened, although I am sure I have missed something. Can someone kindly help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anybody kindly comment if at least **my** approach is correct?

Comment: I think the last parameter in your $f_{\mathrm{Chi}}$ should be $\|y\|/\sqrt{\sigma^2+1}$ instead of $\|y\|/\sqrt{\sigma^2}.$ Then the two expressions might be the same - try writing them out in terms of Bessel functions.

Comment: @Dap, can you kindly elaborate your comment in the form of an answer?

Comment: @Dap you are right. The third argument should be $\|y\|/\sqrt{\sigma^2(\sigma^2+1)}$. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @Dap, thanks for your comment on writing down the series expansion of the Bessel function. I have now verified that the two expressions are indeed the same upto some multiplicative constants. Thanks a lot!